# How to add ComboBox in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, combobox, c#-3.0

Hy I am working on a website and i need a comboBox for my website. I am unable to find any sort that component ion the toolbox list. How i can add combobox in my web? please help me..

Comment: You can use DropDownList, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

try with the open aspx page and go to the toolbox, find the "DropDownList" and drag and drop on the web page.

Thanks
Ganesh

Answer (score 0):

A combo box is a bit different from a dropdownlist. Combo Box resides in Ajax Tool Kit